# How to link GTK-3 static libs through codeblocks? [-ld.exe uncompatible with -libxxxxx.a -ld.exe Cannot find -lxxxxx] error

Tags: codeblocks, gtk3

Using code::blocks 17.02 and gcc 7.3.0 (mingw distro @nuwen.net) I am stuck with this error:

> Cannot find -lgtk-3
>
> Cannot find -lglib-2.0
>
> Cannot find -lgobject-2.0

[image]

even though i have added these libraries in the linker settings. I downloaded the GTK 3 static libraries from: http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/31

I tried to, not link these libraries from the linker settings; then i got undefined functions.

Answer (score 0):

So I was using 32-bit gtk+3.0 libraries, with 64-bit mingw (GCC).
That caused this:

> ld.exe uncompatible with -libxxxxx.a;
>
> ld.exe cannot find-lxxxxx

error.

***Solution***: either replace GTK+'s 32-bit libraries with 64-bit ones to match the 64-bit compiler collection.
Or download mingw32(GCC) 32-bit to match the 32-bit libraries. all should be fine then.

Here:

[image]